Series involing a slowly varying function
Let $\ell$ be a positive measurable function defined on $[0,+\infty)$,
which is slowly varying at infinite, i.e., $\lim_{x\uparrow+\infty}\ell(\lambda x)/\ell(x)=1$ for all $\lambda>1$. Is the series
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\bigg|\frac{\ell(n+1)\ell(n-1)}{\ell^2(n)}-1\bigg|
\end{equation*}
convergent? I am not able to prove that the series converges for any slowly varying function $\ell$, but at the same time I am not able to exhibit a slowly varying function $\ell$ that makes the series not convergent.
I tried many cases: $\ell(x)=\log x$ for large $x$, $\ell(x)=\log\log x$ for large x, $\ell(x)=\exp(\log x/\log\log x)$ for large $x$, etc... In all these cases the above series converges, because there exists a constant $c>0$ such that for all $n\ge 1$
\begin{equation*}
\bigg|\frac{\ell(n+1)\ell(n-1)}{\ell^2(n)}-1\bigg|\le\frac{c}{n^2}.
\end{equation*}

By the Karamata representation theorem, every slowly varying function $l : (0,\infty) \to (0,\infty)$ can be represented as $$
l(x) = \exp\left(\eta(x) + \int_{B}^x \frac{\epsilon(t)}{t}dt\right)
$$
for all $x \geq B$, where $B$ is some positive constant depending on $l$, $\eta(x)$ is a bounded measurable function converging to a finite real number as $x \to \infty$, and $\epsilon(x)$ is a bounded measurable function converging to $0$ as $x \to \infty$.
In particular, suppose that $x > B+1$. We have $$
\frac{l(x+1)l(x-1)}{l(x)^2} \\= \exp\left(\eta(x+1) + \int_{B}^{x+1}\frac{\epsilon(t)}{t} dt + \eta(x-1) + \int_{B}^{x-1} \frac{\epsilon(t)}{t} dt - 2\eta(x) - 2\int_B^{x} \frac{\epsilon(t)}{t}dt\right) \\
= \exp\left(\eta(x+1) + \eta(x-1) - 2\eta(x) + \int_{x}^{x+1} \frac{\epsilon(t)}{t}dt - \int_{x-1}^x \frac{\epsilon(t)}{t} dt\right)
$$
As $x \to \infty$, $\eta(x+1) + \eta(x-1) - 2\eta(x) \to 0$, and the two integral terms converge to $0$, so clearly $$
\eta(x+1) + \eta(x-1) - 2\eta(x) + \int_{x}^{x+1} \frac{\epsilon(t)}{t}dt - \int_{x-1}^x \frac{\epsilon(t)}{t} \to 0
$$
as $x \to \infty$. Therefore, it follows that $$
\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{\exp\left(\eta(x+1) + \eta(x-1) - 2\eta(x) + \int_{x}^{x+1} \frac{\epsilon(t)}{t}dt - \int_{x-1}^x \frac{\epsilon(t)}{t} dt\right)-1}{\eta(x+1) + \eta(x-1) - 2\eta(x) + \int_{x}^{x+1} \frac{\epsilon(t)}{t}dt - \int_{x-1}^x \frac{\epsilon(t)}{t}} = 1,
$$
which is to say that $$
\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{\frac{l(x+1)l(x-1)}{l(x)^2} -1}{\eta(x+1) + \eta(x-1) - 2\eta(x) + \int_{x}^{x+1} \frac{\epsilon(t)}{t}dt - \int_{x-1}^x \frac{\epsilon(t)}{t}} = 1
$$
and by continuity of the absolute value, $$
\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{\left|\frac{l(x+1)l(x-1)}{l(x)^2} -1\right|
}{\left|\eta(x+1) + \eta(x-1) - 2\eta(x) + \int_{x}^{x+1} \frac{\epsilon(t)}{t}dt - \int_{x-1}^x \frac{\epsilon(t)}{t}\right|} = 1
$$
So, ignoring all terms $n<B$, $\frac{l(n+1)l(n-1)}{l(n)^2} -1$ is absolutely summable if and only if
$$
\eta(n+1) + \eta(n-1) - 2\eta(n) + \int_{n}^{n+1} \frac{\epsilon(t)}{t}dt - \int_{n-1}^n \frac{\epsilon(t)}{t}
$$
is absolutely summable. Note that a telescoping argument reveals that it is summable because terms cancel out, but we are looking for absolute summability.

There are two terms in focus, the $\eta(n+1)+\eta(n-1) - 2\eta(n)$ part, and the $\int_{n}^{n+1} \frac{\epsilon(t)}{t}dt - \int_{n-1}^n \frac{\epsilon(t)}{t}$ part.
Let's set $\eta \equiv 0$ and focus on the $\frac{\epsilon(t)}{t}$ part.
Recall that $\epsilon(t) \to 0$, so the way of maximizing the absolute value is to make $\int_{n}^{n+1} \frac{\epsilon(t)}{t}dt$ and $\int_{n-1}^{n} \frac{\epsilon(t)}{t}dt$ have opposing signs for each $n \geq 1$. This necessitates the possibility $\epsilon(t) = (-1)^{N(t)} f(t)$, where $f$ is non-negative, and $N(t)$ is $1$ when $[t]$ is even and $0$ when $[t]$ is odd. Now what happens is that $$
\left|\eta(n+1) + \eta(n-1) - 2\eta(n) + \int_{n}^{n+1} \frac{\epsilon(t)}{t}dt - \int_{n-1}^n \frac{\epsilon(t)}{t}\right| \\
= \left|\int_{n}^{n+1} (-1)^{N(t)}\frac{f(t)}{t}dt - \int_{n-1}^n (-1)^{N(t)}\frac{f(t)}{t}dt\right| \\
= \int_{n-1}^{n+1}\frac{f(t)}{t}dt.
$$
Now, clearly $f(t) \to 0$ as $t \to \infty$, but we can ensure that it goes slowly enough so that the above sequence is not summable. For example, if $f(t) = \frac{1}{\ln(t)}$, then $$
\int_{n-1}^{n+1}\frac{f(t)}{t}dt = \int_{n-1}^{n+1} \frac{1}{t \ln(t)}dt
$$
is not absolutely summable, because $\int_{M}^{\infty} \frac{1}{t \ln(t)}$ is not finite for any $M<\infty$, something that would be implied by the absolute summability of the quantity in question.
Finally, we complete the counterexample by taking some arbitrary $B$, say $B=2$, and setting $$
l(x) = \exp\left(\int_{2}^{x} \frac{(-1)^{N(t)}}{t\ln(t)}dt\right) \text{ for all } x \geq 2,
$$
where $N(t) = 1$ if $[t]$ is even and $0$ otherwise for all $t \geq 2$. $l$ can be set to some arbitrary values for smaller values of $x$, it doesn't appear in the sum anyway.
Note, however, that the sequence in question is always summable, even if not absolutely summable.

Finally, what we notice is that the two terms involving $\eta$ and $\epsilon$ look like the second order differences of these functions. Without providing a rigorous result, this should be the origin of the $\frac{c}{n^2}$ estimate which was proving to be carrying on throughout the examples considered by the OP.

Very interesting! Thank you very much for the deep answer, which allows one to build a lot of  counterexamples. Unfortunately, the fact that the above series can be divergent makes more complex an application that I am dealing with...

@Marco I sincerely wish that your efforts in the end go through. If it gives you solace, you might want to notice that for a large class of functions $l$, the sum is actually finite from the above analysis (and from your own investigations), so hopefully restricting your attention to this class of functions will serve you well. In any case, the representation theorem is your way to go for further series and convergences. Thanks for the illuminating question!
